# typo3 form, use the submitted email as from

Tags: forms, email, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'd like to activate an auto-responder on the e-mail address where I receive the requests from the web-site, for this the mail should be send from the submiter's e-mail ...

```
postProcessor {
    1 = mail
    1 {
        from_email = field.email
        senderEmail = email
    }
}
```

this does not work, I could not find documentation ...

Comment: Which form extension are you using? `EXT:form`, `EXT:formhandler`, or something else?

Comment: Ext:form ... I found this: senderEmailField = email used instead of senderEmail but I think my smtp is refusing it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use replyto instead of setting submiters email as sender due to the spam filters:

```
replyToEmailField = email
```

I was not able to find it in documentation, but in the 7.6 release notes it is mentioned as implemented:

[https://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3.CMS/Releases/7.6/Feature#Feature:*.2368771*-_Add_contentObject_functionality_to_form_MailPostProcessor_and_introduce_replyToEmail](https://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3.CMS/Releases/7.6/Feature#Feature:_.2368771_-_Add_contentObject_functionality_to_form_MailPostProcessor_and_introduce_replyToEmail)

Also relevant forge ticket with code example:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/69395

Comment: Oh yes, by chance I looked at this old question, I did a bunch of manouvres to get my smtp host to accept 'foreign' email-addresses as sender but this answer does it !!

Comment: Just for the record. The documentation can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/. The postProcessor stuff is documented at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/Configuration/Postprocessors/Mail/Index.html.

Since 7.6 most of the postProcessors are stdWrap-able. This is only valid when you're storing your form outside of a content element. This was done because of security reasons.